# Не отрисовывается форма при использовании Thread.Sleep()

Tags: c#, winforms, sleep

Имеется вот такой код:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Shown += new EventHandler(Form1_Shown);
}

private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Refresh();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    this.Hide();
    Form2 mainForm = new Form2();
    mainForm.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```

В плане закрытия/открытия новых форм работает нормально, но при начальной загрузке первой формы происходит следующее:

[image: как выглядит форма]

Попробовал добавить в код `this.Refresh()`, тогда компоненты отрисовались, но нижний прогрессбар не показывал жизни.

Как выглядит форма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли способ отрисовать компоненты? Или как-то заменить Sleep без потери основного замысла?

Answer (score 0):

Заменил `Thread.Sleep()` на `await PutTaskDelay()`

И в код добавил:

```
async Task PutTaskDelay()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: Зачем оборачивать `Task.Delay` в лишний метод? Вызывайте его напрямую.

Comment: @ElephAnt, а если всё-таки так сильно нужен этот метод, то лучше из него возвращать `Task`, а не писать там лишний `await`.

Comment: Можно поставить [AsyncFixer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SemihOkur.AsyncFixer) - бесплатное дополнение к Студии, которое будет показывать ошибки (и способы их исправления) асинхронного кода. Как раз то, о чём говорит CasperSC.

Comment: Спасибо за советы, друзья! Обязательно прочту про AsyncFixer. А метод... потому что копипаста :)